# Marginal R2 for linear mixed models in cross-validation

Tags: r, prediction, cross-validation, mixed-models, variance

For a prediction problem I am working on I want to calculate the variance in the data explained by the linear effects of my linear mixed model. To evaluate my predictive performance I plan on using five-fold cross-validation.

The common approach to this problem I see on the internet is to a marginal R. This can be done with the r.squaredGLMM function from the MuMln package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf) based on work by Nakagawa et al. (2017). As I understand it, his formula divides the variances explained by the fixed effect by the total model variance:

[image]

However, I don't know how to make this formula work in a cross-validation setting as I don't know how to calculate the specific variances for fixed, random, and error in the test dataset. My current solution is to apply the OLS formula (1 - var(fitted)/var(observed)), but this does not match the maximum likelihood approach used in LMMs. It also leads to a negative outcome in some situations.

My question in two stepped:

1. Is there a way to calculate the required variances for the Nakagawa formula?
2. If not, can the 'classic' R2 be applied in this setting?

Comment: If you want to fit a predictive model can you just use raw mean-squared-error on the test set as your criterion? i.e., why do you need to mess with R^2 measures? (Can you provide links to the internet examples you see using marginal R^2 measures?)

Comment: Using a raw RMSE is my current approach for evaluating my own models, but it makes a comparison with the results from for example Dansson 2021 (doi: 10.1186/s13195-021-00886-5) difficult as express their predictive performance using an R^2. Calculating an marginal R^2 would be the closest analogue as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after Nakagawa R2 in mixed models then, `library(performance)` is very helpful. Most people use `library(lme4)` for linear mixed models, `lmer()`, and for generalised ones, `glmer()`. On `lmer()` models, `performance()` defaults to using Nakagawa methods. Then you can use `performance_cv()` for various cross validation methods.

Example:

```r
library(performance)
library(lme4)
data("iris")
test1 <- lmer(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + (1|Species), data = iris, REML = FALSE)
test1
performance(test1)
performance_cv(test1, method = "k_fold", k = 5, stack = FALSE)
```

Should give you results:

```
# Indices of model performance

AIC    |   AICc |     BIC | R2 (cond.) | R2 (marg.) |   ICC |  RMSE | Sigma
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
91.941 | 92.217 | 103.983 |      0.910 |      0.318 | 0.869 | 0.297 | 0.300
> performance_cv(test1, method = "k_fold", k = 5, stack = FALSE)
# Cross-validation performance (5-fold method)

MSE   | MSE_SE | RMSE | RMSE_SE |   R2 | R2_SE
----------------------------------------------
0.095 |  0.036 |  0.3 |   0.059 | 0.46 |  0.24
```

That should help you get started, however I am having a few issues dissecting some of the nuances of these results from the CV, and have posted on StackExchange about them here, [Nakagawa R2 & Cross Validation issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611639/k-fold-cross-validation-using-nakigawa-r2-for-lmer-mixed-model-issues), if anyone can help with that.

Comment: My apologies for the delay in responding. This does solve the problem I had a the time of posting. Thank you! I have now extended the analysis by adding an external validation dataset for my prediction model. If I read the package manual correctly, it cannot calculate an R2 using a different dataset as reference. Do you have a suggestion for calculating an R2 for my prediction model on an external dataset

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "external", but it might be this. In `performance_cv` you can add an argument `data = yourExternalData`, "data 
Optional. A data frame containing the same variables as model that will be used as the cross-validation sample.", so something like this: `performance_cv(test1, data = yourExternalData)` which I think would compare them. I haven't done this before so your mileage may vary.

Comment: This does provide an out of sample R2, but it does not calculate an R2 using the Nakagawa formula (if that is even possible). A conventional R2 leads to very different results for me. Depending on the setting this might work for someone else.

Comment: The cross-validation `performance_cv()` will give you the CV (Nakagawa) marginal R2, which is the R2 of the fixed factors only. In the example I gave, R2(marg.) 0.318, is compared to cross-validated R2 0.46, which is 0.142 difference. Depending on your data, "big" differences may point to problems with over-fitting, as I understand it.